# How to show $z=1$ is a factor without first finding $\lambda$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Question: Given that $e^{i \theta}$ is a root to the equation $$z^3 - (\sqrt{3} +1)z^2+\lambda z - 1 =0,$$ where $0< \theta < \pi/2$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, show that this equation can be factorized as $$(z^2 - 3z \cos \theta +1) (z-1) = 0.$$

My problem: I know that since all coefficients are real numbers, the complex roots are in conjugate pairs. Multiplying out the conjugate pairs I am able to get the quadratic factor. However, I'm not sure how to show that $z-1$ is a factor without first finding the value of $\lambda$? I know that there are three roots, and the last root has to be a real root since otherwise a complex conjugate root also exists, making it four roots in total. I'm sure I'm not supposed to solve for $\lambda$ first because the next part of this question asks us to find the value of $\lambda$ given the above factorization.

This is a homework assignment, so please give me some hints! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the third factor is $z-a$.  What is the constant term of the cubic?

Comment: Ah yes, then $-a$ must correspond to $-1$! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{i\theta}$ is a root,
so is its conjugate.
Their product is 1.

From the constant term,
the product of all the roots
is 1.

Therefore 1 is a root.

You now know all the roots.
Take it from there.